# How do I connect to an AWS Linux machine from WinSCP using pem key

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, winscp

I need to connect to an AWS Linux machine from WinSCP using pem key provided by AWS, how Do I do that? And do I need to create a ppk for that?

Comment: Here, I googled that for you: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_amazon_ec2 In the future, please search for things like this instead of coming here and asking us to search for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that I do need to generate a PPK from the pem I was provided,

So first to create the PPK:

we need putty gen  --> **File** --> **Load private key** --> **browse to the .pem file**  --> **generate**

And you have the ppk.

[image]

Now Just open WinSCP and open a new connection 
insert all the details (ip, user, etc.) and click on the **"advanced.."** tab
Then go to **SSH** --> **Authentication**  --> and browse to the PPK key that you created in **"private key file"**  -->then click **"ok"**.

[image]